# How can I install CWM Recovery on my Galaxy Note?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, rom-manager

I'd like to install CWM Recovery on my Galaxy Note. The build number is DDLPA. I installed ROM Manager but my phone wasn't listed in the options.

I've Googled this but haven't been able to find a reliable file as I'm not sure if my build number is supported.

A link and instructions to CWM Recovery for the DDLPA Galaxy Note would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: DDLPA just means that your Galaxy Note is targeting Indian consumers.  Cant you see N7000 listed in the list that ROM Manager shows? Also can you list the entries that you see related to N7000?

Comment: I can't see my Note there. There's three Galaxy S2s, an Epic4G, and a GalaxyS. Those are the only options I can see. I'm on the latest version of ROM Manager as I just installed it from the Play store.

Comment: As per http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1551216 post, I understand that ROM Manager doesnt support N7000 yet. There is an another post http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_(AT%26T):_Full_Update_Guide and the section "Installing the ClockworkMod Recovery" is what you should do.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. BTW, Narayan, could you tell me what would be my Android OS version. Would that be DDLPA? Where should i check this?

Comment: Settings -> About phone should show it. You can see "Android version" and other details including DDLPA in some other entry in that list. If you want more step by step or interactions, I would suggest to mail me personally. Note to Moderators:I am not sure that this is allowed, but suggested with an assumption that discussion using comment spoils the purpose of this site.

Comment: DDLPA is ICS 4.0.3. Source: http://androidlegend.com/update-samsung-galaxy-note-n7000-with-ics-4-0-3-ddlpa

Answer (score 1):

CWM is not supporting [ROMs and recovery images](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/) for the Galaxy Note yet. It is mistaken with Galaxy SII and other models.

If you are rooting your phone, [DON'T USE THE CWM.ZIP file or you will brick it](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1810954).

I've done it myself without knowing and now I cannot install roms or ever restore factory settings :(

Comment: If you go for the same mistake as I did, just install a SAFE kernel and remove the CWM.ZIP file from your phone

Answer (score 0):

Dr ketan has an excellent [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1329360) on this topic at the forums at xda-developers. I would consider this the definitive guide on how to safely root your Note.